# High Sierra: Can't connect to a xampp server running on another machine after upgrading macOS

Tags: macos, network, wifi, high-sierra, webserver

I have a Xampp web server running on another computer in the local network and **my Mac can no longer access it after updating to High Sierra.**

All other devices I have in the same Wi-Fi network connect to the web server using the server computer's IP address without any issues.

The only thing that changed, as far as I know, is that the Mac was updated to High Sierra.

Any guesses?

Comment: Its an xampp server. The Mac says it cannot find the address (which is an ip4v address) so the request never reaches the server. Had no problem with this before the Sierra uodate

Comment: Can you visit other websites with your Mac?

Comment: I have several ideas on that topic, but the one that hits me most is: Turning the firewall off. Check routing, DNS settings and subnet masks.  Are the interfaces up by default? refresh the DHCP lease if you are working with DHCP.

Comment: From an earlier comment, you mention that it can't find the IP address.  Are you saying it won't resolve?  Can you ping it?  Can you connect if you try using just the IP address?

Comment: Just to add to the questions being asked, can you clarify whether the computer running the Xampp web server is another Mac or a PC and what operating system it's running? Also, any updated details you can share since your last comment a week ago?

Comment: The other thing runs Windows 10. Unfortunately no luck so far so I just moved to my Windows PC for working.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using SSL with certificate that is SHA-1 signed, which was still allowed (with a warning) in macOS Sierra but in macOS High Sierra the connections will fail. I suggest you move to SHA-256 signed certificates for increased security and to avoid connection failures.

Source: [Apple HT207459](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207459)